# Indexing and Querying URLS in Solr

Tags: url, indexing, solr, tokenize, querying

I have a database of URLs that I would like to search.  Because URLs are not always written the same (may or may not have www), I am looking for the correct way to Index and Query urls.
I've tried a few things, and I think I'm close but not sure why it doesn't work:

Here is my custom field type:

```
 <fieldType name="customUrlType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

For example:

http://www.twitter.com/AndersonCooper   when indexed, will have the following words in different positions: http,www,twitter,com,andersoncooper

If I search for simply twitter.com/andersoncooper, I would like this query to match the record that was indexed, which is why I also use the WDF to split the search query,
however the search query ends up being like so:

myfield:("twitter com andersoncooper")   when really want it to match all records that have all of the following separate words: twitter com andersoncooper

Is there a different query filter or tokenizer I should be using?

Comment: did you ever end up sorting this out?

Comment: Did you figure our what needs to be done here?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this statement from your question

> myfield:("twitter com andersoncooper") when really want it to match all records that have all of the following separate words: twitter com andersoncooper

You are trying to write a query that would match both:

```
http://www.twitter.com/AndersonCooper
```

and

```
http://www.andersoncooper.com/socialmedia/twitter
```

(both links contain **all** of the tokens), but not match either

```
http://www.facebook.com/AndersonCooper
```

or

```
http://www.twitter.com/AliceCooper
```

If that is correct, your existing configuration should work just fine.  Assuming that you are using the standard query parser and you are querying via curl or some other url based mechanism, you need the query parameter to look like this:

```
&q=myField:andersoncooper AND myField:twitter AND myField:com
```

One of the gotchas that may have been tripping you up is that the default query operator (between terms in a query) is "OR", which is why the AND's must be explicitly specified above. Alternately to save some space, you can change the default query operator to "AND" like this:

```
&q.op=AND&q=myField:(andersoncooper twitter com)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the most simplest solution:

```
<field name="iconUrl" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

But for you requirement you will need to make it multivalued and index it 1. no changes 2. without http 3. without www

or make the URL searchable via wildcards at the front (which is slower I guess)

Comment: Yeah, `string` if from `StrField`, it won't be analyzed, but could be stored / indexed, it's proper for url, I guess.

Comment: This won't work for the OP's queries which specify only parts of the url

Answer (score -1):

You can try the [keyword tokenizer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters?highlight=%28tokenizer%29%7C%28keyword%29#solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory)

From the book *Solr 1.4 Enterprise Search Server* published by Packt

> KeywordTokenizerFactory: This doesn't
>   actually do any tokenization or 
>   anything at all for that matter! It
>   returns the original text as one term.
>   There  are cases where you have a
>   field that always gets one word, but
>   you need to  do some basic analysis
>   like lowercasing. However, it is more
>   likely that due  to sorting or
>   faceting requirements you will require
>   an indexed field with no  more than
>   one term. Certainly a document's
>   identifier field, if supplied and  not
>   a number, would use this.